# Terraform chicken/egg problem using aws_vpc data source in root module

Tags: terraform

I have a root Terraform module that declares a VPC module and other modules such as an EC2 instance that is to launch in the VPC.

In the EC2 module, I read the VPC using the `aws_vpc` type:

```tf
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  filter {
    name  = "tag:Name"
    values = [var.name_tag]
  }
}
```

Now this works fine if I declare the modules independently.

But when declaring a root module that declares these other modules separately, I get this failure:

```
▶ terraform apply
module.cloudwatch.data.aws_ami.ami: Refreshing state...
module.backend.data.aws_vpc.vpc: Refreshing state...
module.backend.data.aws_ami.ami: Refreshing state...

Error: no matching VPC found

  on .terraform/modules/backend/main.tf line 1, in data "aws_vpc" "vpc":
   1: data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
```

So there is a chicken/egg problem here.

I am confused. How can this ever work? If a root module cannot both declare a VPC and then use the `aws_vpc` data source later to read it into other modules, what is the use of these data sources? I would appreciate advice on the best practice here. Should I simply not use `aws_vpc` and instead read in the VPC ID as an output elsewhere?

Comment: That `data` should probably be an input variable to your `backend` module instead. Specifying the VPC ID as an output from another module to be input to the `backend` module would indeed be a very practical second step. In general, `data` is most helpful in root configs (e.g. retrieving a cross-account `route53`), or inside modules where you would never expect to manage that resource (e.g. `aws_ami` because you manage that with Packer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me this sounds like you are declaring both a resource like

```
resource "aws_vpc" "example" {}
```

AND data-provider like

```
data "aws_vpc" "example" {}
```

in order to access something from the data like `data.aws_vpc.example.arn`. This is not needed and in fact is causing your error. If both is in the same terraform state, you can simply drop the `data "aws_vpc" "example" {}` and refer to the resource by e.g. `resource.aws_vpc.example.arn`.

The data provider is actually only needed in cases in which you are referring to a resource that is created somewhere else like something created manually, by a different provisioning engine (or also by terraform, but in a different layer).

Comment: Yes but I am trying to create composable modules, and module A should not need to reach inside or know the internals of module B. From module B's perspective, it could assume that the VPC exists. Module A's job is to actually create that VPC. But I suspect you are right.

Comment: In this case I would suggest to add a parameter to your module B, which takes e.g. the arn of your vpc. It is usually better to not refer to terraform state in modules and instead use parameters to provide such information.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: There's some more info on that approach in the "Dependency Inversion" section of Terraform's "Module Composition" guide https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html#dependency-inversion

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned your query very specifically.
As far as I understand from your question, you have declared VPC in root module and want to use it's id or arn, etc from this, right? 
So, in this scenario, you must have specify the perfect path of your vpc module in (.) format (e.g. module.root.aws_vpc.vpc_name.id) and also you can use 
`depends_on = [your vpc ]` in your data resource declaration.

NOTE: I don't have required reputation here to suggest you these things as in comments, I may also loos my reputations here by answering you as a answer here.

Request: Please mention more details here, also paste your module tree structure for better understanding.

you can refer this link : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpc.html

Answer (score 0):

> The data provider is actually only needed in cases in which you are referring to a resource that is created somewhere else

An example code that is correct.

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-2"
}

data "aws_vpc" "example" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["TRIAL"]
  }
}

output "show-me-vpc" {
    value = data.aws_vpc.example.arn
  
}
```